# Android - Exception Finalize class having broadcastreceiver inside

Tags: android

I have made a class and inside the class **constructor** I created a **broadcastreceiver** for SMS and in **finalize** method class I do **unregister** the reciver .

Now : my application have 3 tabs each tab have activity when **OnCreate** of the activity I do create instance of my class  (Create BroadcastReceiver for the current activity) and **OnStop** I do finalize to the class.

The problem is when i moving in tabs many time i get force close application with exception as the last show in this post .

MYCLASS CODE:

```
package com.example.tawasol1;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.tawasol1.Cls_stringManager.MessageType;
import com.example.tawasol1.Cls_stringManager.QueryMessge;

abstract class RecieverEvents{
    abstract void OnAccountNotRegistered(String Sender,String Message,String Provider);
    abstract void OnAccountNoBalance(String Sender,String Message,String Provider);
    abstract void OnAccountActivatedOk(String Sender,String Message,String Provider);
    abstract void OnAccountRegisterNoMoney(String Sender,String Message);
    abstract void OnMessage(String Sender,String Message,String FromNumber);
    abstract void OnEnvitationMessage(String Sender,String Message,String FromNumber);


}

public class Cls_CreateReceiver  {
    private Context mContext ;
    private RecieverEvents mReceiverEvnts ;
    private BroadcastReceiver CurrentReceiver ;
    private String smsSender  ;
    private String smsBody  ;
//  private Intent CheckPage ;



    Cls_CreateReceiver(Context c ,int Priority,  RecieverEvents RecEvents){
        mContext =c ;
        mReceiverEvnts = RecEvents ;


        //====================== Body Of receiver 

        IntentFilter fp=new IntentFilter();
        fp.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        fp.setPriority(Priority);


        CurrentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context conx, Intent recIntent) {



                    //===================== Get Message Extras  
                Bundle IntExtras = recIntent.getExtras() ;
                 if (IntExtras == null)
                       return;
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) IntExtras.get("pdus");

                // get message from bundle intent 
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {

                      SmsMessage SMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                      smsSender = SMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                      smsBody = SMessage.getMessageBody().toString();

                        }    

                    //======================End Message Extras      

                Boolean isSystemMessage = false ;
                QueryMessge retMsgQuery = QueryMessge.None ;    

                cls_database smsCheck =  new cls_database(mContext) ;
                Cls_stringManager StrManager = new Cls_stringManager();


                isSystemMessage = smsCheck.isOurSystemMessage(smsSender);

                //================= isSystemMessage     
                if (isSystemMessage)
                {
                this.abortBroadcast() ; 





                        if (StrManager.isQueryMessage(smsBody))
                        {

                            Log.d("isQueryMessage:", "YES");

                            retMsgQuery = StrManager.GetQueryMsg(smsBody) ;

                            switch (retMsgQuery) {
                            case None:
                                // Toast.makeText(c,"Error Message Query Type" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;

                            case NoBalance :
                                mReceiverEvnts.OnAccountNoBalance(smsSender, smsBody, "");
                                    break ; 
                            case AccountActivated :

                                mReceiverEvnts.OnAccountNotRegistered(smsSender, smsBody, "");
                                break ;
                            case NoRegisteredAccount :
                                mReceiverEvnts.OnAccountNotRegistered(smsSender, smsBody, "") ;

                                break ;
                            default :
                                Log.d("Receiver Other Msg:", smsBody);
                                Log.d("Receiver Other Msg:", smsSender);

                                if(smsSender.equals("TASHBIK"))
                                {
                                    Log.d("Receiver Other Msg:Tashbik", smsBody);
                                    mReceiverEvnts.OnAccountRegisterNoMoney(smsSender, smsBody) ;

                                }

                            } //switch Case 




                        }//StrManager.isQueryMessage
                        else
                        {
                            Log.d("isQueryMessage:", "NOT");

                            if (StrManager.isAccountExpireNoRegistered(smsBody)){
                                mReceiverEvnts.OnAccountNotRegistered(smsSender, smsBody, "") ;
                            return;
                            }

                            if (StrManager.isNoBalaceMessage(smsBody)){
                                mReceiverEvnts.OnAccountNoBalance(smsSender, smsBody, "") ;
                            return;
                            }


                            String ChatterMobile = "" ;
                            String ChatterMessage="" ;

                            MessageType MsgType = MessageType.None ;

                            MsgType = StrManager.GetMessageType(smsBody);


                            Log.d("Reciver>HasBody:", StrManager.hasBody(smsBody).toString());
                            Log.d("Reciver>HasMobile:", StrManager.hasMobile(smsBody).toString());

                            Log.d("Reciver>Mobile:", StrManager.GetMobileFromMessage(smsBody));
                            Log.d("Reciver>Msg:", StrManager.GetMessageBody(smsBody));

                            if(StrManager.hasMobile(smsBody))
                                ChatterMobile = StrManager.GetMobileFromMessage(smsBody);

                            if (StrManager.hasBody(smsBody))
                                ChatterMessage = StrManager.GetMessageBody(smsBody);



                            switch (MsgType) {
                            case Chatting:
                                mReceiverEvnts.OnMessage(smsSender, smsBody, "CHAT");
                                break;
                            case DirectMessage:
                                mReceiverEvnts.OnMessage(smsSender, ChatterMessage.trim(), ChatterMobile.trim());
                                break;
                            case Invitation :
                                mReceiverEvnts.OnEnvitationMessage(smsSender, smsBody, ChatterMobile.trim());
                                break ;
                            default:

                                if(smsSender.equals("TASHBIK"))
                                {
                                    Log.d("Receiver Other Msg:Tashbik", smsBody);
                                    mReceiverEvnts.OnAccountRegisterNoMoney(smsSender, smsBody) ;

                                }

                                break;
                            }








                        }//StrManager.isQueryMessage

                }//================= isSystemMessage or Not





            } // End onReceive event

 };
//====================End Of Receiver 


        mContext.registerReceiver(CurrentReceiver,fp);

} //End Of Constructor 

public void UnregisterReceiver(){
    mContext.unregisterReceiver(CurrentReceiver);

}   


@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {

    mContext.unregisterReceiver(CurrentReceiver);

    super.finalize();
} 



}
```

ERROR LOG :

```
03-04 14:48:57.331: E/System(22346): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
03-04 14:48:57.331: E/System(22346): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.example.tawasol1.Cls_CreateReceiver$1@41d64278
03-04 14:48:57.331: E/System(22346):    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:654)
03-04 14:48:57.331: E/System(22346):    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1297)
03-04 14:48:57.331: E/System(22346):    at com.example.tawasol1.Cls_CreateReceiver.finalize(Cls_CreateReceiver.java:223)
03-04 14:48:57.331: E/System(22346):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:186)
03-04 14:48:57.331: E/System(22346):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:169)
03-04 14:48:57.331: E/System(22346):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: finalize() is really not a good place to unregister receiver. Have You tried to move it for example to activity onPause() callback?

Comment: in finalize  class i do unregister receiver but in OnStop Event for activity i do finalize class.

Answer (score 0):

The `onCreate` method is called only the first time your Activity is created (or if this one has been finished)

But the `onStop` method is called as soon as the `Activity` isn't visible anymore

So the next time your `Activity` isn't shown, you try to unregister your receiver which is already unregistered

You can move your `Receiver` creation to the `onResume` method which is called every time your `Activity` is shown

You can see the `Activity` lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: the tabs destroy activity when you move to another tab , and creating the selected one. so i think OnCreate and OnStop is the right place to create and destroy the receiver .

Comment: What kind of Tab component are you using ?